# Depurar groovy de un Jenkisfile

Tags: jenkins

Me gustaría poder depurar un Jenkinsfile (groovy), poder poner puntos de interrupción, usar las funciones de Jenkins en dicho groovy, vamos, lo que es un entorno de programación con todas sus funciones.

Sabeis que debo instalar en una máquina local para hacerlo.

Actualmente edito con Visual Studio Code, Gracias :-)